# Is this valid CSS? Why or why not?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

```
.9-bucks {
    font-size:  60px;
}
```

This is the error I am getting when I push my app to Heroku:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was "9-bucks {"
2012-06-07T11:42:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS selector names (either IDs or class names) cannot begin with a number...
http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Try replacing with `.nine-bucks {  }`

Answer (score 1):

I dont think css class or ID names can start with a number. Have you tried using 'nine' instead of '9'?

Answer (score 0):

> W3C reference on naming classes in css and not using a number in the
>   first position of the class name. Best thing to do is to use only an
>   alpha character as the first letter in your class name (a-z). You can
>   then use numbers after that.

Answer (score 0):

yes change your **html** - **class="9-bucks"** to **class="nine-bucks"**

and change **css** file - **.nine-bucks{ // }**

Comment: using numbers up front is against W3C standards so its better to use alphabetic characters